# applying a mask on a nested numpy array - numpy - python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, slice

a bit embarassing to ask since the heavy documentation on Numpy but I was stuck doing this simple task, that is getting all the records for which a mask is true in a nested numpy representation (equivalent to the `dataframe.loc[cond]` in `pandas`):

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.array([1,2,3])
a2 = np.array(['a','b','c'])
a3 = np.array(['luca','paolo','francesco'])
a4 = np.array([True, False,False], dtype='bool')

combination = np.array([a1,a2,a3,a4])
print(combination)

# slice for a4 == True 
combination[combination[3] == 'True']
```

but the result is not what I want.

in fact from `combination` :

```
[['1' '2' '3']
 ['a' 'b' 'c']
 ['luca' 'paolo' 'francesco']
 ['True' 'False' 'False']]
```

it yields with `combination[combination[3] == 'True']`:

```
array([['1', '2', '3']], 
      dtype='<U11')
```

when in reality I want:

```
[['1']
 ['a' ]
 ['luca']
 ['True' ]]
```

any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

P.S.: no i can't do it in pandas because pandas has my RAM exploding when converting this to a `pandas.Dataframe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're simply missing the indices of the other dimension:

```
combination[combination[3] == 'True']
```

should be

```
combination[:, combination[3] == 'True']
```

Note the colon.

This yields a new ndarray indexed over all of the first dimension and only 0 in the second.

Comment: I feel like smashing the keyboard after realizing this. Thank you for your quick answer!